# Facebook Settings iOS 6 - App Name not showing in Allow Apps list

Tags: iphone, facebook, settings, ios6, facebook-login

In iOS 6, the user can login to Facebook via Settings>Facebook. There is a section on that view where the apps for which the user may choose to allow/disallow use of the Facebook account are listed.

I have integrated the FacebookSDK.framework into my app, and a line appears for the app in this list. Only, the name of my app is not listed, and neither is its app icon.

I have done several searches and can't seem to find a way to get the name/icon added to the list. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the account store methods to request access:

```
-(void)authenticateFacebook {
if([UIActivityViewController class] ) {
    NSArray *faceBookPermissions = @[@"publish_stream"];
    ////ACFacebookAppVersionKey: @"1.0",

    NSDictionary *faceBookOptions = @{
ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"xxxxxxxx",
ACFacebookPermissionsKey:faceBookPermissions,
ACFacebookAudienceKey:ACFacebookAudienceFriends
    };

    AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if(del.accountStore == nil) {
        del.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    }
    if(del.facebookAccount == nil) {
        ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [del.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
        [del.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
                                                   options:faceBookOptions
                                                completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             if (granted) {
                 NSArray *accounts = [del.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
                 del.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                 NSLog(@"got an account");
                 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(gotAnAccount) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"No account");
                 //fail gracefully
                 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(noAccount) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

Once that is done you can post to facebook with your app id as follows:

```
    -(void)postToFacebook:(NSDictionary *)parameters  {

    AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                      URL:feedURL
                                               parameters:parameters];
    request.account = del.facebookAccount;
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSString *alertText;
        if (error) {
            alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                         error.domain, error.code];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(errorWithRequest:) withObject:alertText waitUntilDone:NO];
        } else {
            alertText = @"Posted action, id: %@";
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(cancelButtonAction:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

        }
        NSLog(@"%@",alertText);
    }];
}
```

You'll need your app delegate to have the accountStore and account variables and then create the @selector methods used. Note that the completion handlers should run on the main thread if they do anything with the UI or you'll be sat waiting a while for the completion handler UI code to run.

Comment: This looks like a great answer, but is it this question that you meant to answer? I could easily be missing something, just wanted to check.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand about using the AccountStore to gain access to an account - when we ask for the account, it gets added to the list. But, considering the new 3.1 SDK, do we need to do this every time the user logs into the app?

Comment: You'll use this code instead of the 3.1 SDK since you're using native integration. If you go with the 3.1 SDK you don't need to use the native integration or see your app in the FB list.  Native is great for silent posts from an app or creating a custom FB sheet. I've found the native code to be faster too.

Comment: Just to add a little note, the App name only shows up on the Allow apps list once the user has actually tried to access the account.

Comment: @earnshavian If I post on facebook wall using SLRequest with paramters , I can see shared via <app_name> , but when I use SLComposeViewController , I seee shared via via iOS on Facebook wall. Why I am not seeing my app name instead of iOS ?

Comment: @earnshavian: Hi...it seems u r going to app delegate to get the methods for "accountStore" and "facebookAccount". I don't want to go to the app delegate. I want to call those methods from my present class itself. So, is this code correct?
http://pastie.org/8035948